# which phase is configuration phase in java program execution?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, gateway

Martin Fowler references *configuration time* in his book **Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture** while explaining Gateway and Service Stub.

> You can switch between the real service and the stub at configuration time using Plugin(499).

I want to understand what is configuration phase in Java.

Comment: Don't remember the phase names, but it's the phase where you *install* the code into its runtime environment (dev, test, prod, ...). I'm unsure if that is even a dedicated phase, or just the "operations" phase, where you maintain the runtime environment, at least for production.

Comment: will just installing code in any runtime environment be part of java runtime ? Configuration phase is part of java runtime i strongly feel but not sure.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about an actual code sample? There is no 'configuration phase' as such in the Java runtime. Perhaps some frameworks have the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with Dependency Injection, *configuration time* is the phase in which dependencies are chosen, instantiated, and wired together at runtime. Avoiding hard-coded (compile-time) dependencies allows an app to be deployed in different environments without recompiling it.

A number of design patterns can be employed to initialize an app's configuration at runtime, one of which is the Plugin pattern Fowler references. On page 499, its purpose is stated as,

> *Links classes during configuration rather than compilation.*

So configuration time is contrasted with compile time, i.e. it is part of the runtime of an application, specifically the initial phase in which dependencies are wired together. One ubiquitous case for configuration is testing: you need a real database connection in production, but an in-memory database is sufficient for test. At some point your app must determine which connection to establish, and provide a reference to that connection to some service. This is the configuration phase.

You can switch between the real database and the stub at configuration time using Plugin.